How to customize the OpenAPI Spec for Make.com request and response models?
It seems like many OAS json files do not make use of the $ref when generating out the OpenAPI spec so the models end up being generically called Body3, Body4, Response5, Response6, etc.
I have tried using the classNames property in the nswag file but it doesn't seem to do anything upon generating the client.
I have this example method:
Task<Response106> FunctionsEvalAsync(int teamId, Body37 body = null, 
   CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));

I would like to rename the models to be like:
Task<FunctionsEvalResponse> FunctionsEvalAsync(int teamId, FunctionsEvalRequest body = null, 
   CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));

Even better if there was a tool or method to relink (via $ref?) the original models and make use of their names in a strongly-typed manner.
MyProject.csproj:
<ItemGroup>
    <OpenApiReference Include="OpenAPIs\openapi.json" CodeGenerator="NSwagCSharp" Options="/GenerateClientInterfaces:true /injectHttpClient:true" ClassName="MakeClient">
        <SourceUri>https://us1.make.com/api/v2/openapi.json</SourceUri>
    </OpenApiReference>
</ItemGroup>

Generated IMakeClient Interface:
public partial interface IMakeClient
{
    Task<Response> LoginAsync(Body body);
    Task<Response> LoginAsync(Body body, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    Task<Response2> LogoutAsync();
    Task<Response2> LogoutAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    Task<Response3> AuthorizeAsync(Body2 body);
    Task<Response3> AuthorizeAsync(Body2 body, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    Task<Response4> Login2Async(Body3 body);
    Task<Response4> Login2Async(Body3 body, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    Task<Response5> TeamsGETAsync(int organizationId, string externalId, PgOfSortBy? pgsortBy, int? pgoffset, PgOfSortDir? pgsortDir, int? pglimit);
    Task<Response5> TeamsGETAsync(int organizationId, string externalId, PgOfSortBy? pgsortBy, int? pgoffset, PgOfSortDir? pgsortDir, int? pglimit, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    Task<Response6> TeamsPOSTAsync(Body4 body);
    Task<Response6> TeamsPOSTAsync(Body4 body, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    Task<Response7> TeamsPATCHAsync(int teamId, Body5 body);
    Task<Response7> TeamsPATCHAsync(int teamId, Body5 body, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    Task<Response8> TeamsDELETEAsync(int teamId);
    Task<Response8> TeamsDELETEAsync(int teamId, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    Task<Response9> OrganizationsGETAsync(int? id, string name, string externalId, IEnumerable<string> cols, string pgsortBy, int? pgoffset, PgOfSortDir2? pgsortDir, int? pglimit);
    Task<Response9> OrganizationsGETAsync(int? id, string name, string externalId, IEnumerable<string> cols, string pgsortBy, int? pgoffset, PgOfSortDir2? pgsortDir, int? pglimit, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    Task<Response10> OrganizationsPOSTAsync(Body6 body);
    Task<Response10> OrganizationsPOSTAsync(Body6 body, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    Task<Response11> OrganizationsPATCHAsync(int organizationId, Body7 body);
    Task<Response11> OrganizationsPATCHAsync(int organizationId, Body7 body, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    Task<Response12> OrganizationsDELETEAsync(int organizationId);
    Task<Response12> OrganizationsDELETEAsync(int organizationId, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    Task<Response13> UsersDetailAsync(int? id, string name, string email, IEnumerable<string> cols, PgOfSortBy2? pgsortBy, int? pgoffset, PgOfSortDir3? pgsortDir, int? pglimit);
    Task<Response13> UsersDetailAsync(int? id, string name, string email, IEnumerable<string> cols, PgOfSortBy2? pgsortBy, int? pgoffset, PgOfSortDir3? pgsortDir, int? pglimit, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    Task<Response14> UsersGETAsync(int? organizationId, int? teamId, string name, string email, int? teamRoleId, int? organizationRoleId, IEnumerable<string> cols, PgOfSortBy3? pgsortBy, int? pgoffset, PgOfSortDir4? pgsortDir, int? pglimit);
    Task<Response14> UsersGETAsync(int? organizationId, int? teamId, string name, string email, int? teamRoleId, int? organizationRoleId, IEnumerable<string> cols, PgOfSortBy3? pgsortBy, int? pgoffset, PgOfSortDir4? pgsortDir, int? pglimit, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    Task<Response15> UsersPOSTAsync(Body8 body);
    Task<Response15> UsersPOSTAsync(Body8 body, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    Task<Response16> UsersPATCHAsync(int userId, Body9 body);
    Task<Response16> UsersPATCHAsync(int userId, Body9 body, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    Task<Response17> UsersDELETEAsync(int userId, bool? deleteConnections, bool? confirmed);
    Task<Response17> UsersDELETEAsync(int userId, bool? deleteConnections, bool? confirmed, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    Task<Response18> UserOrganizationRolesPOSTAsync(int userId, int organizationId, IEnumerable<string> cols, bool? deleteConnections, bool? confirmed, Body10 body);
    Task<Response18> UserOrganizationRolesPOSTAsync(int userId, int organizationId, IEnumerable<string> cols, bool? deleteConnections, bool? confirmed, Body10 body, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    Task<Response19> TransferAsync(int userId, int organizationId);
    Task<Response19> TransferAsync(int userId, int organizationId, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    Task<Response20> UserTeamRolesPOSTAsync(int userId, int teamId, Body11 body);
    Task<Response20> UserTeamRolesPOSTAsync(int userId, int teamId, Body11 body, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    Task<Response21> DefaultLicenseAsync();
    Task<Response21> DefaultLicenseAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    Task<Response22> CustomThemePOSTAsync(Body12 body);
    Task<Response22> CustomThemePOSTAsync(Body12 body, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    Task<Response23> CustomThemesAsync();
    Task<Response23> CustomThemesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    Task CustomThemeDELETEAsync(int id);
    Task CustomThemeDELETEAsync(int id, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    Task<Response24> CustomThemePATCHAsync(int id, Body13 body);
    Task<Response24> CustomThemePATCHAsync(int id, Body13 body, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    Task ActivateAsync(double id);
    // .... more methods follow ....
}

